# How to accept arrays in my defined function

Tags: function, idl-programming-language

When I try to feed the following function an array, it gives me the following error: % Expression must be a scalar or 1 element array in this context: .  How to modify such that I can either give it a scalar or array?

---

```
; return integer -1, 0, or 1, depending on whether x is less than 0, equal to 0, or greater than 0, respectively
function whatisit, x
  case 1 of
    (x lt 0): y=-1
    (x eq 0): y=0
    (x gt 0): y=1
  endcase
  return, y
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function whatisit, x
  return, x gt 0 - x lt 0
end
```

EDIT: For pedagogical reasons, I will show the ugly (untested) looping solution, but you should never do this in IDL:

```
function whatisit, x
  n = n_elements(x)
  result = bytarr(n)
  for i = 0L, n - 1L do begin
    case 1 of
      x[i] lt 0: result[i] = -1
      x[i] eq 0: result[i] = 0
      x[i] gt 0: result[i] = 1
    endcase
  endfor
  return, size(x, /n_dimensions) eq 0 ? result[0] : result
end
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, Mgalloy. Your solution works, but my original aim was to learn how to loop through arrays (or scalars) using the kind of control statement provided above--do you know how I might be able to achieve that?

Comment: In IDL, you do not want to loop through elements of an array when you don't have to; there is a definite performance penalty. I will submit another non-vectorized solution.